# Typoscript issue with GP vars?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I want to execute a query using typoscript . My query is

`SELECT * FROM TABLE where sld like '{GP:SID}'` . I want to warp the SID variable inside a single/double quotes. Tried the below script, but didnt worked for me.

```
lib.products = CONTENT
lib.products {
  table = TABLE
  select {
    pidInList = 26506
      orderBy = name
      where = sid like '{GP:SID}'
   }
   renderObj = COA
   renderObj {
   10 = COA
     10 {
     10 = TEXT
     10.dataWrap ={field:name}[\n]
    }
  }
```

}

Can any help me with this ?

Comment: Please do not ask the same questions in multiple boards. You already go the same answer from a different person on the TYPO3 CMS mailing list. Now two people needed to take time to answer you, while at least one of them could have helped someone else. Please ask your questions at one place at a time.

Comment: @pgampe Next time onwards I will take care of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You code is insecure! Don't use it on production.

What you should do instead - is to use [TS query markers](http://buzz.typo3.org/teams/core/article/safety-and-flexibility-in-typoscript-queries/), which uses prepared statements in a background.

```
lib.products = CONTENT
lib.products {
  table = TABLE
  select {
    pidInList = 26506
      orderBy = name
      where = sid like '###sid###'
      markers {
        sid.data = GP:SID
      }
   }
   renderObj = COA
   ...
}
```

Also, if you want to use LIKE, you need % sign to make it work, otherwise it is same as 'equals', but slower. However, I'm not sure, what happens, if GP:SID contains % sign at the beginning or at the end of a string.